# Dgraph: Is it possible to store arrays natively?

Tags: dgraph

When I tried to store an array like `test: []string{"hello", "bye"}` using `dgo` and queried for `test`, I only get back `"hello"`. Seems like the closest way to store an array in Dgraph is to create multiple objects and point them towards a single node. If that is the case, how would you store a list of fixed length? or ensure the number of list nodes does not exceed the intended list size (e.g. having a todo list with only 10 slots)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create and get an array of string as follows

```
**Query to create array of strings** 
{"set":[{
  "StringArray" : ["Hi", "hello"]

}]}

**Query to fetch array of strings** 
{q(func:has(StringArray)){
  uid
  StringArray
}}
```

In dgraph it is called as **List Type**
Ref: https://docs.dgraph.io/query-language/#list-type

Comment: "A set operation adds to the list of values. The order of the stored values is non-deterministic." Is there a way to store arrays of primitive types that retain their order? I'm thinking you stringify an array and store it as a string.

Comment: @sdfsdf It's not currently possible to save values as a true list, your proposal to stringify the array is the only way.